# Carthage update terminal error = Illegal Instruction: 4

Tags: swift, xcode, csv, command-line, carthage

I am making a project that needs external data.

I found a framework to parse CSV data for a program written in Swift. However, I have been having some issues with importing this into my program using Carthage. I downloaded Carthage using Homebrew, then created a cartfile in my project file. The issue arises here, in the command line:

```
Charles-MBP:StoryboardTutorial crich$ carthage update
Illegal instruction: 4
```

My program file contains [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkmBk.png)

Alternatively,

Is there a better way to import an table of string data into an xcode project?

Comment: I have not solved the issue regarding the importing of a framework, but I did figure out that converting the csv to a plist and putting it in the project file is the easiest way to bring data into the program.

Comment: I know that its not an answer, but if you didn't used any dependency manager you can use natively supported Swift Package Manager. Try https://github.com/skelpo/CSV for example.

Comment: @MichaelPohl I made my way around using any packages by simply using plists instead of csv data, as explained above. However, I will use SPM for future problems. Thank you!